# Why does firefox require credentials to load an image?

Tags: asp.net, security, firefox, configuration, image

I am running a website on a virtual directory.

The url for the site is `http://localhost/virtalDirectory/pages.aspx`

I have an image to be loaded on the page from the following directory heirarchy:

`parent directory

..images

....my image

..myPage.aspx`

My img tag is 
`<img src="images/imageName.gif" alt="some text"/>`

When loading in IE8, the images are loaded properly, but when loading in Firefox3 I am prompted to log into localhost and it appears to be a windows file explorer login.

I have a web.config in the images directory:

`<system.web>

<authorization>

<allow users="*" />

</authorization>

</system.web>`

I have tried changing my image tag to:
`<img src="~/images/imageName.gif" alt="some text" runat="server"/>` to allow asp to resolve the address of the image at run-time. Which does not resolve the problem.

I have tried adding <allow users="?" /> to the image directory web.config. Which does not resolve the problem.

Comment: This is a great example of why I still occasionally slip into rants against Microsoft. This smacks of Microsoft making IIS/ASP.NET working great with IE, and failing on everything else.  My guess is that IE8 magically knows how to authenticate using your windows credentials.

Good luck.

Comment: @Triptych: While I'm not a Micro$oft apologist, I think this it's unlikely they went to so much trouble to handicap someone else's free browser in favor of their own free browser.

Comment: @Tom:  What version of Windows/IIS?  Have you tried browsing directly to the image in both IE and Firefox?  What happens when you browse from a remote system?

Comment: @Dave: It's more like they make things work as long as you're using Microsoft all the way up and down the pipeline, without any regard whatsoever to other products, or industry standards. They're getting better, but I've done enough battling with IE6 to earn the right to say the above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions on the file itself?  Most likely, the file permissions are set to you vs. everyone, and IE passes the credentials along but Firefox doesn't.

Comment: In the OS. Right-click on the file, "Properties" > "Security"

Comment: If you're using IIS and/or your web app to handle access, the file must be readable by the IUSR_<whatever> account.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy There is another image in the same directory that is viewable without logging in, that does not have the Security settings updated.

Comment: The permissions on the two files are the same?

Comment: No they are not, now that I have added Read access to "machineName\Users" FF does not require credentials. Thanks GC!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with file permissions, or Microsoft trashing other browsers. There is just a small mistake in your markup, which IE decides to fix for you on the fly, and FireFox chooses not to.

You should use a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) as the value of the src [as the HTML standard dictates](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.2).
Contrary to Windows file paths, URIs use a forward slash (/) instead of a backslash (\) as a hierarchy separator

IE is just more forgiving for the markup mistake and will silently fix up the path.
If you want make FireFox act as forgiving as IE, install [Slashy](http://gemal.dk/mozilla/slashy.html).

The most preferable solution by far is to [write valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

```
<img src="images/imageName.gif" alt="some text"/>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I had included forward slashes in the original image URI, I changed them around when copying the code to the question. I think that because FF was asking for credentials, it had found the correct image file and came up against the permissions rather than just not displaying the images. A VERY good point on the slashes though, that I will be mindful of in future, thank you. I use Validator based on TIDY for FF (http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/), but in this case I had neglected to check it, so another very good point. Thanks Peter.